# Is it possible to create a ciphersuite for TLS 1.3 using only the Keccak-sponge/duplex?

Tags: tls, sha-3, keccak, sponge

Now that Keccak has been chosen as SHA-3 we see that there have been defined quite a few related modes, including authenticated cipher modes, the KMAC message authentication mode, XOF's and whatnot. However, it is unclear to me how much this fills all the gaps for symmetric cryptography. Could we for instance define and implement a TLS 1.3 cipher suite to use just constructions solely based on the Keccak-sponge/duplex as primitive? Simple bit operations and loops are of course permitted to tie everything together.

So besides KMAC we'd likely need to have a well defined and preferably standardized KDF and a secure random number generator (preferably one that can be reseeded). Additional points go to the answer that also manages to indicate a method of authentication (hash-based signatures?) and, possibly more tricky, a key agreement scheme to replace (EC)DH.

Comment: "a secure random number generator"; actually, a TLS ciphersuite does not define the random number generator.  You could certainly create a good rng from SHA3 (e.g. use it in a HASH-DRBG construction), it's just not negotiated in TLS

Comment: That's true of course, but it does require a source of random numbers (if just to generate random keys for the ephemeral key agreement). So although it isn't defined in the cipher suite it is required to implement it - I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: IIRC CAESAR had a Keccak-based submission and then you could use KMAC as your PRF. It turns out I was thinking of Ketje and Keyak.

Comment: @poncho HASH-DRBG have some [problems](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75198/36960) that may prevent it from being instantiated with SHA-3.

Comment: Note: against common belief it seems certainly possible to use key encapsulation using an ephemeral key pair to achieve forward security and replace (EC)DH. The problem with e.g. RSA is that it is very slow when it comes to key generation (due to the requirement to find equally sized primes that together dictate the key size), so using RSA encryption for forward security is not recommended. However, to my knowledge, there is no key encapsulation algorithm defined that only relies on the Keccak sponge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First for the scope of such a ciphersuite, to quote [RFC 8446 Section B.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8446#appendix-B.4):

> A symmetric cipher suite defines the pair of the AEAD algorithm and hash algorithm to be used with HKDF.

Now to the first question:

> Could we for instance define and implement a TLS 1.3 cipher suite to use just constructions solely based on the Keccak-sponge as primitive?

With the above definition of what a cipher suite is, this seems easy enough, we just pair either of [Keyak](https://keccak.team/keyak.html) or [Ketje](https://keccak.team/ketje.html) with SHA-3 or [KangarooTwelve](https://keccak.team/kangarootwelve.html). One of the first two mentioned AEAD schemes would be mostly used for bulk encryption and one of the latter two hash functions via HKDF for key derivation. I'm not sure how much customization TLS 1.3 allows but it *might* also be possible for an RFC to define Keccak based ciphersuites to use a different KDF than HKDF, though this would most likely lower acceptance.

> Additional points go to the answer that also manages to indicate a method of authentication (hash-based signatures?)

Indeed it would be possible to use either of the hash-based NIST PQC Round 3 Alternative candidates for this. In fact [Picnic](https://microsoft.github.io/Picnic/) is already based on Keccak (and LowMC to build a MPC-based signature scheme). Additionally [SPHINCS<sup>+</sup>](https://sphincs.org/) is also specified for SHAKE-256 for the NIST PQC.

> and, possibly more tricky, a key agreement scheme to replace (EC)DH.

Constructing key agreement (or public-key encryption) from hash functions is very unlikely even for theoretical constructions (assuming collision-resistance). It is very much impossible to do so generically only assuming the existence of black-box One-Way-Functions as shown by [*Rudich and Impaglazzio in STOCS 1989's "Limits on Provable Consequences of One-way Permutations" (PDF)*](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.14.6170&rep=rep1&type=pdf).

Comment: That leaves the random number generator, but as there are counter based ones out there it would be rather simple to construct one even with reseeding. Nice. Shame about the key agreement but very expected :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm personally optimistic that in the future, once we found a wide permutation of sufficient efficiency, we'll be more motivated to define internet protocols (for example, TLS 1.4 or 1.5) to be parameterized exclusively by the permutation it uses.

Following the format of the answer by SEJPM,

> A symmetric cipher suite defines the the pair of the AEAD algorithm and hash algorithm to be used with HKDF.

First, the AEAD algorithm can and have already had been defined in terms of a mode of operation of a permutation.

Secondly for key derivation, it's the hash algorithm to be used with HMAC for instantiating HKDF. As already noted in the OP, there's already KMAC. HMAC requires at least 2 invocations of the hash function, so it's plausible we may want to replace it with special designs that're specific to the underlying primitive to obtain more efficiency - for example, KMAC as in the case of Keccak, or Keyed BLAKE2 in the case of ChaCha (the latter of which is unlikely since the ChaCha function is slightly different for the cipher and for the hash).

Thirdly, we may not need dedicated MAC if we can prove the tag of the AEAD algorithm is computationally random, and can obtain arbitrary-length tag from it. In this case, even the HKDF construction is partially redundent, as in the extract and expand steps are preserved, but they no longer rely on MACs.

> Additional points go to the answer that also
> manages to indicate a method of authentication (hash-based signatures?)

Of course hash-based signatures. As already mentioned by SEJPM, Keccak-based hash functions had already been proposed to instantiate the SPHINCS+ signature. What I'd like to add, is that the actual SPHINCS+ and its underlying XMSS and WOTS signatures rely on randomized and parameterized hashing to reduce the size of the signature, these signature schemes may benefit from hash functions instantiated from e.g. TupleHash as specified in [NIST SP-800-185](https://doi.org/10.6028/NIST.SP.800-185) in terms of performance and bandwidth efficiency.

Also, there's the stateful hash function that are slightly more efficient than the stateless ones. According to [NIST](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/Stateful-Hash-Based-Signatures), they intend to approve stateful hash signatures in some applications, including for example: code signing. Similar applications could potentially include OCSP the Online Certificate Status Protocol, and CRL the Certificate Revocation Listing, as these data change much slower than ephemeral key-exchange public keys.

> and, possibly more tricky, a key agreement scheme to replace (EC)DH.

I [agree with SEJPM](https://crypto.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1122) in that asymmetric key exchange is improbable with hash functions, or symmetric-key primitives in general.

While TLS do have the option to use Kerberos for handshake, after quickly going through [RFC 4120](https://tools.ietf.org/html/4120) and IANA registery for Kerberos 5, I realize that Kerberos is a protocol with so many legacy artifacts that, if we were to advocate Keccak for the protocol, it would cause massive incompatibility and interoperability problems with existing implementations.

The idea of Kerberos is still applicable, in that in a large network, KDC can maintain a database of keys for the nodes in the network, and lifts from each node the burdon of maintaining PSKs for all peers.